# Handle EventEmitterModule wildcards - NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I don't know how to handle the following emitter:

```
async create(createJobDto: CreateJobDto)  {
    this.eventEmitter.emit(
        ['job','create'],
        createJobDto,
    );
}

async update(createJobDto: CreateJobDto)  {
    this.eventEmitter.emit(
        ['job','update'],
        createJobDto,
    );
}
```

Listener:

```
@OnEvent('job.**')
handleJobEvent(data: CreateJobDto) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The NestJS and the EventEmitter2 docs mention that I can use an array as a wildcard, but how can I distinguish between "create" and "update" in the listener? All that I seem to get in `data` is the job object.

P.S. I am correctly including the EventEmitterModule in my imports:

```
EventEmitterModule.forRoot({
  wildcard: true
}),
```

Comment: Did you try `@OnEvent('job.*)` with only one `*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's not possible. You have to create two different listeners:

```
@OnEvent('job.create')
handleJobCreateEvent(data: CreateJobDto) {
    console.log(data);
});

@OnEvent('job.update')
handleJobUpdateEvent(data: CreateJobDto) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The NestJS docs do allude being able to do it: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events#listening-to-events

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, we have an `emitter.event` property that identifies the currently fired event. So the NestJS emitter wrapper should have it too. Here's an example from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter2#differences-non-breaking-compatible-with-existing-eventemitter):

```
emitter.on('foo.*', function(value1, value2) {
  console.log(this.event, value1, value2);
});

emitter.emit('foo.bar', 1, 2); // 'foo.bar' 1 2
emitter.emit(['foo', 'bar'], 3, 4); // 'foo.bar' 3 4

emitter.emit(Symbol(), 5, 6); // Symbol() 5 6
emitter.emit(['foo', Symbol()], 7, 8); // ['foo', Symbol()] 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks - I understand that is how to do it through the emitter, however the listener in the NestJS wrapper doesn't seem to handle it same way the eventemitter2 listeners do. I think @Terenoth was correct in the end.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't there a ref to the emitter inside the method like `this.eventEmitter`? If the event emitter is an EventEmitter2 instance this should work `this.eventEmitter.event`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your shared link: http://%20docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events#listening-to-events, the correct syntax would look something like:

@OnEvent('order.*')

In your case:

@OnEvent('job.*')

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to override the emit function using a wrapper provider or create an enhanced version of the emitter, that will add the event name as the first/last value or modify the first parameter, however you like.

For example:

```js
import { Global, Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventEmitter2, EventEmitterModule as EventEmitterModule2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import { event, eventNS } from 'eventemitter2';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export const EVENT_EMITTER = 'EventEmitter';

export interface EventEmitter extends EventEmitter2 {
  emitWithName: (event: event | eventNS, ...values: any[]) => boolean; //copy of the signature of emit function
}

const eventEmitterFactory: Provider = {
  provide: EVENT_EMITTER,
  useFactory: (eventEmitter2: EventEmitter2) => {
    const emitWithName = (event: event | eventNS, ...values: any[]): boolean => {
      if (_.isObject(values[0])) {
        values[0].event = event;
      }

      const valuesWithName = [...values, event];

      const result = eventEmitter2.emit(event, ...valuesWithName);
      return result;
    };

    Object.assign(eventEmitter2, { emitWithName });
    return eventEmitter2;
  },
  inject: [EventEmitter2],
};

@Global() //because EventEmitterModule is a global dynamic module
@Module({
  imports: [
    EventEmitterModule2.forRoot({
      wildcard: true,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [eventEmitterFactory],
  exports: [eventEmitterFactory],
})
export class EventEmitterModule {}
```

In app.module you need to import this module, and to inject the provider:

`@Inject(EVENT_EMITTER) private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something very similar but with patterns and apparently, it's not possible right now. So I'd say use a different decorator-line for each one.

Like

```
@OnEvent('job.create')
...
...
...
@OnEvent('job.update')
```

Also good to keep an eye on the opened thread: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3083